# CodeNameOne - Replacing an image in generated Android source code

Tags: android, image, codenameone

In the codename one project I loaded an image to the .res file as multiImage. It looks okay in most devices, but on certain android devices like the Samsung S3 it looks either pixelated or obviously resized depending on which resolution or size I load to the .res file. Therefore I wanted to change it directly in the generated android code, usually for Android I would use different images and put them in the different drawable-xxx folders, but when looking at the generated code the src/main/res is empty and all the images from /src and the .res file are in the assets folder.

Is there no way to modify a multiImage for certain resolution from the android project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right way to do it as the native device would still look in the res file.

You need to open the res file in the designer and select the multi image then you can use the combo box to pick the right resolution and the `...` button to replace it with a different image. If you have an image editor like photoshop you can use the `Edit` button to edit the image in place.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, did you mean "with a different image" here "with a different app"?